# Send data from silverlight application to a particular user in mvc application

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller

I have an mvc application where you have to be registered to log in. So you have your profile page and etc...  As a part of the application I have a chat for all users (silverlight page). You enter the chat from your profile page. You have a list of online users there (who logged in on the site and not necessary entered the chat page) but exchange messages you can just with users who did enter the chat page. Otherwise they won't see them. Here is my problem.
So, I want to realize next functionality: if user who didn't enter the chat page was chosen by another to start conversation in chat (silverlight), he should get a pop up message on HIS profile page (mvc) with invitation to the chat. I understand how to send data from silverlight to mvc through WebClient and json format. I don't understand how to reach  particular user's profile page. I can think just about some database table with this kind of invitations and some timer on the profile page to check on them.
Please express your ideas, thoughts or opinions in this matter. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by 'how to reach particular users profile page'. Are you assuming the recipient has the page open on their client and you're not sure how to send the invitation to them, or is it assumed that they may not have the profile page open at all and you're not sure how to send the chat invitation to a client who doesn't currently have their profile page open on their computer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check out SignalR.

Like you mentioned you need some way to signal another client about the message by checking periodically. SignalR does this for you and in modern browsers uses Websockets to make it even better.

It is very easy to setup and you can build a chat application in a few lines of code. Without the need to save messages in a database (when you don't want to).

Check out this blog post for a sample chat application:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx